# Failed to sync Gradle project - Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I've recently updated to Android Studio 2.2 and changed Gradle plugin version to 2.2.0 `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0`.

Now I'm getting the following error when trying to sync Gradle files:

> Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class
>   'com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Property'.

If I change Gradle plugin version to 2.1.3, the problem disappears. How I can use the latest version 2.2.0?

P.S. I'm also using gradle-experimental for NDK support - `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3`

Comment: post build.gradle code.

Comment: There are several gradle files in the project, but there is no `com.android.builder.profile.Recorder` in any of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I   solved the problem by updating gradle-experimental to version 0.8.0 :)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.0"
```

hope this will fix it for you too and will not generate new errors!